# Spring Batch: Writer is not being called if Reader reads nothing

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a `Step` in my job that reads from database A and then writes to database B & C.

If the select statement yields no results i want to expect it to continue to the `processor` and `writer` as usual. However, the `writer()` is not called!

This is because my `writer` is a Composite item writer which has a writer that updates a control table (database C) to say the reader read no results.

I would obviously have a new Tasklet `Step` to follow this `Step` in question, but its a partitioned step.

Is there a configuration property for the `Job` that allows empty reads to not be marked as 'NOOP' or similar, but as successful?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use a `StepExecutionListener` for this use case instead of an `ItemWriter`.  Within that `StepExecutionListner#afterStep` you can look at the items read count and if it's 0, do that db update.  The writer piece is an `ItemWriter`, meaning it is intended to be used to write items that have been read.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom `ItemReader` that return a sentinel item if no items are read.
Add a custom `ItemWriter` mapped to sentinel item class where you update the control table.